# SVG or Canvas, how to cut square by coords and div size

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg, canvas

My problem is next.
How do I generate an SVG or Canvas to be like full screen page overlay (50% transparent). But I want to highlight some div below this overlay. I know the coordination's and width-height of that div. How do I cut out area according to that div on my overlay so that area is fully transparent and see that div clearly? That div will be on different places on different pages. I'm not good at canvas nor svg. please help me.

Comment: Define “highlight”. _“How do I cut out area according to that div on my overlay so that area is fully transparent and see that div clearly?”_ - why do you not place that element on top of the canvas to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need. On the DOM you have 2 divs: the `#square` and the `#circle`.

I'm using a semitransparent (opacity .9) overlay that gets clipped over the `#square`. Please read my comments.

```js
var SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
// define the position of the #square
let _left = 120;
let _top = 230; 
let w = 150;
let h = 150;

// recalculate the points needed for the clip-path
 let p = svg.createSVGPoint();
 p.x = _left;
 p.y = _top;
 let ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
 p =  p.matrixTransform(ctm);

 let p1 = svg.createSVGPoint();
 p1.x = w;
 p1.y = h;
 let ctm1 = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
 p1 =  p1.matrixTransform(ctm1);


//define the d for the clip path
let oClipRect={
  d:`M0,0L100,0L100,500L0,500L0,0
  M${p.x+p1.x},${p.y}
  L${p.x},${p.y}
  L${p.x},${p.y+p1.y}
  L${p.x+p1.x},${p.y+p1.y}
  L${p.x+p1.x},${p.y}`,
  id:"clip_rect"
}

//a big overlay rectangle that gets clipped
//The rectangle is semitransparent so that you can see the the circle
let oRect={
  width:"100%",
  height:"100%",
  "clip-path":"url(#_clip)",
  fill:"rgba(0,0,0,.9)"
}


drawElmt(oClipRect,"path", _clip);
drawElmt(oRect,"rect", svg);

// function update needed on resize
function update(){
 p = svg.createSVGPoint();
 p.x = _left;
 p.y = _top;
 ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
 p =  p.matrixTransform(ctm);

 p1 = svg.createSVGPoint();
 p1.x = w;
 p1.y = h;
 ctm1 = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
 p1 =  p1.matrixTransform(ctm1);
 
 d = `M0,0L100,0L100,500L0,500L0,0
  M${p.x+p1.x},${p.y}
  L${p.x},${p.y}
  L${p.x},${p.y+p1.y}
  L${p.x+p1.x},${p.y+p1.y}
  L${p.x+p1.x},${p.y}`;
  console.log(d)

 clip_rect.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);
 
}



setTimeout(function() {
  update();
  addEventListener('resize', update, false);
}, 15);




function drawElmt(o,el, parent) { 
  var elmt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, el);
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      elmt.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(elmt);
  return elmt;
}
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#wrap {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.test {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}

#square{background: gold;left: 120px;
  top: 230px;}

#circle{background:red;left: 150px;
  top: 270px;border-radius:50%;}

svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="square" class="test"></div>
<div id="circle" class="test"></div>
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 500">
  <clipPath id="_clip">
          
  </clipPath>  
</svg>
</div>
```